# Is it possible to define multiple predicates between a subject and object in RDF?

Tags: graph, nodes, rdf, edges

I want to persist a RDF Graph, where the predicates are the property edges and the subjects/predicates are the nodes. Now I want to know if multiple edges between two nodes are possible and legal in the rdf semantic.

As example:

Tom -loves->julia
Tom -liveswith->julia

Is this in this form possible? Or would I model this in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible.  It's just two triples.  E.g., in Turtle, it might look like:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>.

:Tom :loves :Julia .
:Tom :livesWith :Julia .
```

or even more concisely:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>.

:Tom :loves :Julia ;
     :livesWith :Julia .
```

A RDF graph is just a set of triples.  There's no constraint on how many of those triples happen to have the same subject and object.

In fact, since RDFS has a subPropertyOf relationship, having multiple relationships between the same resources is pretty much required.  E.g., you might have:

```
:hasSon rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasChild .
```

That means that when you have

```
:X :hasSon :Y
```

you can *infer*

```
:X :hasChild :Y
```

which is another triple that relates the same subject and object.